# What's on the sign behind the guy with all the weapons in episode 8?

Tags: japanese-language, hajimete-no-gal

In episode 8 of *Hajimete no Gal*, at around 12:59, Ranko mentions that there's tight security around the women's bath at the inn they're staying at, and then there's a cut to this sign:

[image]

It reads 完全被甲混乱, and was subtitled by Crunchyroll as "Full Metal Jacket". Is this right? If so, how does [*Full Metal Jacket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Metal_Jacket) have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 8):

Surprise - it's a subtitling error! The first four characters (完全被甲) certainly mean "full metal jacket" (in the sense of a bullet with a full-metal jacket). But the last two ([混乱](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B7%B7%E4%B9%B1)), which seemingly went untranslated, mean "confusion" or "disorder"... or, perhaps, "Panic". You know, as in *Full Metal Panic!*.

So, what does *Full Metal Panic!* have to do with anything?

I have a pretty good guess: [episode 9 of *Full Metal Panic? Fumoffu*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqR4mKGLFMU) features the cast visiting a hot springs resort. Once there, some of the men (led by military man Kurz) attempt to spy on the girls in their party as they relax *au naturel* in the open-air hot springs. Like Junichi's friends in *Hajimete no Gal*, Kurz-and-co's efforts are indeed foiled by rather tight security. I suppose this was a homage of sorts.

Comment: That's why when I was watching this episode of Hajimete no gal, I was remembering somewhere this scene was related to Full metal panic.. now this make sence..